# PlatformNotSupportedException Loading .NET 2.0 in .NET 4.0 Process

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm attempting to load a .NET 2.0 assembly into a C# .NET 4.0 PowerShell module. If I attempt to reference the assembly, I get a PlatformNotSupported message indicating the 2.0 assembly doesn't support .NET 4. I'm also loading the 2.0 assembly via reflection.

I tried creating an net40AssemblyName.dll.config with the below configuration, but that doesn't work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <configuration> 
        <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
             <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
        </startup>
    </configuration>
 </xml>
```

I'm unsure if this is due to the dll.config not working, or if this would have to be applied at the PowerShell.exe.config level.

Comment: Are you sure .NET 2 is installed? Usually config settings have to go in the app.config file.

Comment: @RonBeyer not sure it's possible to *not* have 2.0 installed.  It might have something to do with the powershell host, so that startup config would have to be applied to powershell, not your dll.  Maybe. I think it's getting a bit deep out here, I'm going to swim towards the shore. Good luck.

Comment: @RonBeyer, yep, .NET 2 is definitely there. Will, that is kind of what I'm thinking, that it may apply to PowerShell.exe and not my DLL. Easy to test, not so friendly to implement, nor would I necessarily want to as it would impact anything loaded in PS.

Comment: @Trevor, do both assemblies have the same bitness? It *looks* like your .NET 4 assembly targets x86 and your .NET 2 assembly targets x64.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, both must be x64. My .NET 4 module is built with an x64 target.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up separating out the specific cmdlet that targeted one platform vs. another into separate projects. I was then able to package both projects into a single MSI and provide an option during installation about which platform to target.